# How to append() an element and set its style with css() at the same time with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I tried: `$('#canvas').append('<div class="tile"></div>').css({left: leftPos, top: topPos});`, but that sets the style of `#canvas` rather than the appended element.

I then tried: `$('#canvas').append(('<div class="tile"></div>').css({left: leftPos, top: topPos}));`, but that gives the error "Object `<div class="tile"></div>` has no method 'css'".

How can I add the element and set its style at the same time?

Comment: If you change your second answer slightly it'll work, `.append((` should be `.append($(`...but I posted some cleaner/more usable methods of accomplishing the same thing below :)

Comment: Oh yes, of course! Because the jQuery function will then return the element it has selected/created, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('<div class="tile"></div>').css({left: leftPos, top: topPos})
                             .appendTo('#canvas');
```

This creates the element, styles it, then uses [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) to put it in the same place.

Alternatively, if you're using jQuery 1.4, you can specify the properties, including CSS when you create it, like this:

```
$('<div />', { class:'title', css: {left: leftPos, top: topPos}})
   .appendTo('#canvas');​
```

For more on this method, look at the [`jQuery()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), specifically the `jQuery(html,props)` section.

Comment: Would this be the best way to do it? `$(document.createElement('div')).css({left: leftPos, top: topPos}).addClass('tile').appendTo('#canvas');`

Comment: @Acorn - That's equivalent too...it's whatever style is most pleasing to your eyes I suppose :) Unless you're creating a **lot** of these, there's not much of a performance difference.